# Why error occurs on input text html element?

Tags: angular

I use angular 8.

Here is html code:

```
   <div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
        <h2 class="text-center">Add fridge type</h2>
        <div class="card mt-3">
            <div class="card-body">
              <form [formGroup]="newFridgeType" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4">Title </label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="text" />
                  <label class="col-md-4">Description </label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="description" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-4" [disabled]="todoForm.invalid">Add</button>
                    <a [routerLink]="['/fridgetypeList']">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-4 ml-1">Back</button>
                  </a>
                  </div>
              </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is component defenition:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
import { FridgeTypeService } from './fridgeType.service';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'fridgeType-add',
  templateUrl: './fridgeType-add.component.html',
  //styleUrls: ['./todo-add.component.css']
})

export class FridgeTypeAddComponent implements OnInit {

  newFridgeType: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, 
              private router: Router, 
              private fridgeTypeService: FridgeTypeService) 
              { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.newFridgeType = this.formBuilder.group({
      text: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    debugger;
    this.fridgeTypeService.save(this.newFridgeType.value)
      .subscribe(res => {
          let id = res['_id'];
          this.router.navigate(['/fridgetypeList']);
        }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
  }
}
```

In console I on this row:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="text" />
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (FridgeTypeAddComponent.html:11)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:45294)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44277)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:44565)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44278)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:44594)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44272)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
```

Any idea why I get error above?

Comment: I guess the error comes from `todoForm.invalid` What is `todoForm` supposed to be?

Comment: what is todoForm - where this is defined in class file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `newFridgeType` for disabled attribute in your HTML instead ot todoForm

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-4" [disabled]="newFridgeType.invalid">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are referencing a **todoForm** (`[disabled]="todoForm.invalid"`) but your form, as I can see in your code, is named `newFridgeType`

Answer (score 0):

todoForm is not defined anywhere. So doing .invalid on it causes the error.  You need to define what todoform is.

Answer (score 0):

Your form group is named "newFridgeType" so you have to use it in place of "todoForm" in your html (submit button).